# Showing $f(x,y) - f(0,0) = (x-y) \cdot p(x,y)$ (Newtons Differential Equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the differential equation: $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{dx}f(x,y)= 3\,x^2-2\,a\,x+a\,y+(-3\,y^2+a\,x)\,y' = 0$.

I figured $f(x,y) = x^3-y^3-a\,x^2+a\,y\,x $

However In order to show the statement above I start struggling. At first glance it confuses me, that $f(0,0) = 0$. Why writing $f(x,y) - f(0,0) = (x-y) \cdot p(x,y)$ instead of $f(x,y) = (x-y) \cdot p(x,y)$. Secondly provided $f(0,0) = 0$. How do I find $p(x,y)$? I tried polynomial division but with 2 variables it's kinda odd...

$\textbf{Edit:}$ Polynomial Division somehow works:

$\begin{align}
&x^3-y^3-a\,x^2 + a\,y\,x \quad\textbf{:}\quad (x-y) = x^2 +y\,x-a\,x+y^2\\
-(&\overline{x^3-y\,x^2)}\\
-y^3+&0\,\,+y\,x^2-a\,x^2 + a\,y\,x\\
-(&\overline{0\,\,+y\,x^2-y^2\,x)}\\
-y^3+&0\,\,+0\quad+y^2\,x-a\,x^2+a\,y\,x\\
-(&\overline{0\,\,+0\quad+0\quad-a\,x^2+a\,x\,y)}\\
-y^3+&0\,\,+0\quad+y^2\,x+0\\
-(&\overline{-y^3\quad\,\,\,\,\, +y^2\,x+0)}\\
\end{align}$

Is this the justification for $f(x,y) = (x-y) \cdot p(x,y)$?

Comment: I ran $f(x,y)/(x-y)$ in Matlab and it gave me $x^2+x\,y-a\,x+y^2$. This sounds reasonable, but I'm clueless how to prove it.